# Redirect to another page and change div content of these page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when user register successfully then action attribute of registration form redirect him to login.html. I want to change a div text for informing him that his registration is successful. **I can't understand that how can change div text after redirect.**

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change text on another page unless you have script on that page for that purpose.

You are better off using server-side code to change the message.  For instance, using php, you would have a login.php page that take a parameter called success, so you would call `login.php?success=1` if your login succeeded, and the php script would add the message to the page.

This is just one example of how it might be done, but the key is that you cannot change content on a subsequently loaded page from script on your current page.

**Now**, if you want to use script, you could use jQuery to load the `login.html` content into your current page context, using `.ajax()` or any of the ajax jQuery functions `.post()`, `.get()`, etc.  Then you can use your script to change the content, because it will be in your current page.